# Chrome debugger - Avoid stepping into Node.js internals?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, debugging, visual-studio-code

When using the Chrome debugger, I would like to avoid stepping into Node.js internals.
In VSCode, this can be achieved with the `skipFiles` option in CLI or in `launch.json`.

Is there a similar capability in the Chrome debugger that is not documented anywhere, or a workaround? Manually stepping over iteration of `active_hooks` in `internal/async_hooks.js` (event loop implementation) is not exactly convenient.

Thank you for the help :)